# Not getting proper format while creating table

Tags: html, html-table

I am creating a table and when I am giving **tr** after **th** tags it is going just top of  what is the problem in this code?

This is the error I am getting

[image]

Comment: do you have a  html code to show us?

Comment: Yes i have but i don't know how to format and post here

Comment: You can create a JSFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/ or click on `<>` and copy your code when you edit your question.

Comment: Post your HTML code. You might be missing `<td>` or `<th>` tags.

Comment: Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/2kxdne8o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `<td></td>` tag to "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT".

Like this:

```
    <tr style="padding: 15px ;text-align: center">


         <td style="padding: 15px">MON</td>


         <td style="padding: 15px"> JAVA</td>
         <td> FLAT</td>          
         <td>TEA BREAK </td>
         <td> .NET</td>
         <td> E M</td>
         <td>LUNCH BREAK </td>
         <td> .NET</td>
         <td> CN</td>
         <td> DBMS</td>         
    </tr>
```